# What is this red glowing thing I've found in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I just started playing Terraria, so forgive me if this is obvious. When mining, I found a cave with water, and at the bottom of the pool I found this strange red glowing block.

[image]

I don't think it's crimtane, as (correct me if I'm wrong) it only spawns in Crimson biomes. Could someone tell me what this is? I can't mine it, but I'm using a "candy cane pick" I found in my inventory. (Guessing christmas)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a Crimson Altar, the crimson alternative to the [Demon Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Altar).

It's used as a crafting station to make most pre-hardmode boss items, and Night's Edge.

If you attempt to break it before defeating Wall of Flesh or with a hammer of lesser quality to the Pwnhammer, it will damage you for half of your health.

Comment: One minor correction, if you try to break it in a world that is pre-hard-mode it will damage you for half your health, whether or not you have the Pwnhammer.